# Fresh Type Argument open-close

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

I run into following saying from [C# in Nutshell](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=HrE5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA128#v=onepage&q&f=falsese).

> **Technically, all type arguments on a subtype are fresh: you could say
>   that a subtype closes and then reopens the base type arguments.** This
>   means that a subclass can give new (and potentially more meaningful)
>   names to the type arguments it reopens:
>
> ```
> class List<T> {...}
> class KeyedList<TElement,TKey> : List<TElement> {...}
> ```

I don't understand how the circumstance written in bold is carried out, i.e. close-reopen.

Comment: I believe *clear* could be more understandable there. What they mean is that `T` from the base type doesn't appear in the subtype until you introduce it (under a new name perhaps) and map to one of base type's type arguments.

Comment: @WiktorZychla would you mind exemplifying via IL code or something similar way?

Comment: I will try to answer the question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they mean here is that the subclass has its own, completely independent list of generic arguments and the generic argument from the base class is not automatically "inherited" by the subclass.

Instead of *closes and reopens* they could have said *clears and recreates*.

But what's the rationale behind this *clearing*? Why the subclass type argument is not automatically inherited? The answer is simple - this way you are allowed to have a subclass that has *less* generic arguments than its base class.

Consider following examples:

```
public class TheBase<T> { ... }

// This subclass clears the list of generic parameters
// by instantiating T with int. Thus, the subclass has 0
// generic arguments
public class TheSubclass : TheBase<int> { ...

// This subclass reuses and gives a new name to the base class type argument
// The T from the base class is named TheType here.
// The subclass has 1 generic argument
public class AnotherSubclass<TheType> : TheBase<TheType> { ...

// This subclass reuses the generic argument but also introduces its own.
// It has 2 generic arguments. 
// Base class' T is called U here.
public class YetAnothersubclass<U,V> : TheBase<U>
```